# Error: Cannot find module dotenv

Tags: node.js, npm, módulo-ecmascript

Eu fiz a instalação do `modele` como Dev:

```
C:\Users\mrgen\OneDrive> npm i dotenv --save-dev
    npm WARN Cadastro@1.0.0 No description
    npm WARN Cadastro@1.0.0 No repository field.        

    audited 299 packages in 3.987s
    found 0 vulnerabilities
```

O arquivo de configuração foi atualizado corretamente:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Foi realizada a importação do arquivo com `require()`:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu executo o arquivo, veja o que acontece:

```
C:\Users\mrgen\OneDrive> node src/index

module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'dotenv'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mrgen\OneDrive\src\index.js:14:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

Isso não acontece se eu instalat dotenv no projeto. Eu estou chamando o módulo de forma errada? Por que o node não consegue localizar o módulo?

Comment: Você tem certeza que o environment está setado como dev?

Comment: Onde eu vejo isso?

Comment: Olá, você instalou o modulo no diretório `C:\Users\mrgen\OneDrive>` certo, porém na _stack_ ele aponta que você está neste diretório `C:\Users\mrgen\OneDrive\cursos\javascript\pesquisas\cadastro\src\index.js`, é bom verificar os diretórios em questão

Comment: hum... eu diminuí o tamanho do diretório para ficar mais limpo (formatado), mas está tudo em C:\Users\mrgen\OneDrive\cursos\javascript\pesquisas\cadastro\. Mas acabei de editar a pergunta.

Comment: Tente instalar as dependências do projeto, deve ser isso.
Pode ser com o comando yarn